# Script keeps falling

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a code. It's logic is at first to get file from a client (uploadFile), then load it to another server (changeImage), then load the answer (loadFile). It's all done with promises to chain them together but it doesn't work. It keeps to fall dawn. I have tried to change it a lot. Well actually I spent this whole day trying. But there is no result. In this version it's falling without any mistakes in console. Can you help me?

```
<pre>
var fs = require('fs'),
  http = require('http'),
  url = require('url'),
  multiparty = require('multiparty'),
  request = require('request');

var server = new http.Server();

var ifs = require('os').networkInterfaces();
var result = Object.keys(ifs)
  .map(x => [x, ifs[x].filter(x => x.family === 'IPv4')[0]])
  .filter(x => x[1])
  .map(x => x[1].address)[2];
console.log('\nUse this ip: ' + result);
console.log("Successfully started\n");

server.listen('80', result);
server.on('request', onRequest);

function onRequest(req, res) {
  var parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);
  switch (parsed.pathname) {
    case '/':
    case '/index.html':
      fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, file) {
        if (err) res.end();
        res.end(file);
      });
      break;
    case '/file':
      uploadFile(req)
        .then(function(a) {
          return changeImage({
              'uploadfile': fs.createReadStream('./files/temp.jpg'),
              'ef-set': 10,
              'ef-set-2': 10,
              'jpeg-quality': 80
            }, 'https://www.imgonline.com.ua/grid-square-result.php',
            'http://www.imgonline.com.ua/',
            new RegExp(/download\.php\?file=.+?\.jpg/))
        })
        .then(function(link) {
          //it falls before here because console.log('H') here won't show 'H' :-|
          loadFile(link);
        })
        .then(function() {
          return changeImage({
              'uploadfile': fs.createReadStream('./files/temp.jpg'),
              'efset1': 2,
              'outformat': 2,
              'jpegtype': 1,
              'jpegqual': 85,
              'jpegmeta': 1
            },
            'https://www.imgonline.com.ua/add-effect-black-white-result.php', '',
            new RegExp(/https:\/\/.+?\.jpg/)
          );
        })
        .then(function(link) {
          loadFile(link);
        })
        .then(function() {
          res.end('files/temp.jpg');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('ERR ', err);
        });
      break;
    default:
      fs.readFile('./' + req.url, function(err, file) {
        if (err) res.end();
        res.end(file);
      });
  }
}

function uploadFile(req) {
  if (fs.existsSync('./files/temp.jpg')) {
    fs.unlink('./files/temp.jpg', function(err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
    });
  }
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      var path = files.uploadfile[0].path;

      fs.copyFile(path, './files/temp.jpg', function(err) {
        if (err) reject('ERRinCOPYING');
        fs.unlink(path, function(err) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          var a = 0;
          var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (fs.existsSync('./files/temp.jpg')) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              resolve();
            }
          }, 10);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

function changeImage(formData, url, link, regExp) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.post({
      url: url,
      formData: formData
    }, function(err, resp, body) {
      if (err) reject('ERRinREQUEST: ' + err);
      link += body.match(regExp);
      if (link.length > 32) {
        resolve(link);
      } else {
        reject('ERROR! LINK WAS NOT FOUND');
      }
    });
  });
}

function loadFile(link) {
  request
    .get(link)
    .on('response', function(response) {
      response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./files/temp.jpg'));
    });
}
</pre>
```

The thing is if I comment the uploadFile() and run the rest of the script then everything works fine, and the opposite if I comment the rest of the script and leave only uploadFile() uncommented then again everything works.
Console shows nothing. Just on the client side I see the rejection of the connection. But nothing in the console. If I put console.log() right in 'return new Promise()' in changeImage it will show nothing

UPD: I ran the script with "node server" not as usual with "supervisor server" and it started to work without failings. But why? :\

Comment: what's failing? what's the console output?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into a file system permission issue. When you run the script via `node server` as you mention, the process does not have the permission, which you do have when executing via `supervisor server`.